# Solve $\int x^2\sqrt {1+4a^2x^2}\ dx$ without trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have the integral

$$\int x^2\sqrt {1+4a^2x^2}\ dx$$

where *a* is a constant. When I tried to solve this through substitutions such as $u=4a^2x^2$ or $u=1+4a^2x^2$ or through integration by parts, I just ended up making the equation even more complicated and even harder to solve.

When I asked for help, I got answers asking me to do it through trigonometric substitutions such as $$x=\frac{\tan(u)}{2a}$$

As I have not learnt this yet, is there another way of solving this integral without using a complicated substitution like above?

Upon researching, I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124998/how-to-integrate-without-trigonometric-substitution), but I was not sure how to connect it to my question.

**Edit:**

This integral was obtained for solving the surface area of a wine barrel formed through a solid of revolution.

The equation for the solid of revolution was a parabola as:

$$f(x) = Ax^2 + B$$

This was substituted into the surface area of the solid formed when this is rotated fully about the x-axis:

$$\int_a^b2f(x)\pi \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$$

I split the integral into 2 parts and factored out the A to obtain the simplified integral above.

**Edit**

Mike's answer seems to be working; however, as the procedure for partial decomposition was very lengthy. I used Wolfram's partial fraction decomposer tool and got the following decomposition

[decomposition into partial fractions result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCIoI.png)

Comment: Where did this integral come from? Even with the suggested trig substitution it still seems rather complicated to solve.

Comment: @DavidK I updated the question with how I obtained the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you multiply and divide by x?

$$\int x^3\sqrt{x^{-2}+4a^2}dx$$

This will be off by a sign if x is negative.  Continuing from here:

$$u=x^{-2}+4a^2,du=-2x^{-3}$$
$$\int x^3\sqrt{x^{-2}+4a^2}dx=-\frac12\int x^6\sqrt{x^{-2}+4a^2}(-2x^{-3}dx)=-\frac12\int(u-4a^2)^{-3}\sqrt udu$$
$$u=v^2,du=2vdv$$
$$-\frac12\int\dfrac{2v^2dv}{(v^2-4a^2)^3}$$

Assuming this is all correct, the next step should be to use partial fractions.

Comment: I went through it and it makes sense all the way until the last step. When I am decomposing the fraction into partial fractions, I am only able to get one of the numerators.

Comment: Nevermind, I used Wolfram's partial decomposer and placed the result above. I just have to add all the integrals and I think the integration is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. How about you try or heard of Euler Substitution? Wikipedia has a dedicated article regarding to that method.

Your integral $$ \int x^2 \sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} \, dx$$

Can be solved Euler’s Substitution. Your square root function follows the format $ \sqrt {ax^2 + bx + c}$ where $a = 2a $, $b = 0 $, and $c = 1$ (remember that this is commutative). According to wikipedia, the first Euler Substitution can be used when a > 0. Because $4a^2$ is positive for all values of a, we can use this to manipulate our original equation into $x \sqrt a + t$.

We will make a substitution by introducing a new variable “t”. Utilizing our first Euler Substitution, we’ll have

$$ \sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} = 2ax + t$$

The purpose of Euler Substitution is to express every function of x in terms of t. By doing so, we’ll have

$$ \sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} = 2ax + t$$
Squaring both sides, we have
$$ 1 + 4a^2x^2 = (2ax + t)^2$$ 
Expanding the binomial expression gets us
$$ 1 + 4a^2x^2 = 4a^2x^2 + 4axt + t^2$$
Subtracting $4a^2x^2$ on both sides
$$ 4axt = 1 - t^2 $$
Finally, dividing both sides by $4at$ gives us
$$ x = \frac{1 - t^2}{4at}$$

If we differentiate both sides, we get
$$ dx = -\frac{1}{4at^2} -\frac{1}{4a} dt$$
$$ dx = -(\frac{1 + t^2}{4at^2}) dt$$

The integral is now
$$ -\int (\frac{1 - 2t^2 + t^4}{16a^2t^2})(\frac{1 + t^2}{4at^2})[2a(\frac{1 - t^2}{4at}) + t] dt $$

Cleaning things a bit
$$ -\frac{1}{64a^3} \int [\frac{(1 - 2t^2 + t^4)(1 + t^2)}{t^4}][(\frac{1 - t^2}{2t}) + t] dt $$

$$ =-\frac{1}{64a^3} \int [\frac{(1 - 2t^2 + t^4)(1 + t^2)}{t^4}][(\frac{1 + t^2}{2t})] dt $$

$$ =-\frac{1}{128a^3} \int [\frac{(1 - 2t^2 + t^4)(1 + t^2)(1 + t^2)}{t^5}] dt $$

$$ =-\frac{1}{128a^3} \int [\frac{(1 - 2t^2 + t^4)(1 + 2t^2 + t^4)}{t^5}] dt $$

Notice that you can expand the trinomial by making use of an analogy; squaring a trinomial. Recall that $(a + b + c)^2$ can be expanded into $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +2ab + 2bc + 2ac$. We will use this information to expand and collect like terms in our integrand’s numerator. By doing so,

$$ (1 - 2t^2 + t^4)(1 + 2t^2 + t^4) $$

expanding gives
$$ 1 - 4t^4 + t^8 + 2t^4 $$

which simplifies to
$$ t^8 - 2t^4 + 1 $$

Thus, the equivalent integral in terms of t is
$$ -\frac{1}{128a^3} \int [\frac{t^8 - 2t^4 + 1}{t^5}] dt $$

Term-wise simplification from the integrand gives
$$ -\frac{1}{128a^3} \int [t^3 - \frac{2}{t} + \frac{1}{t^5}] dt $$

By integration, we get
$$-\frac{1}{128a^3} [\frac{1}{4}t^4 - 2ln|t| - \frac{1}{4t^4}] $$
$$=-\frac{1}{128a^3} [\frac{1}{4}t^4 - \frac{1}{4t^4} - 2ln|t|] $$
$$=-\frac{1}{128a^3} [\frac{1}{4}(t^4 - \frac{1}{t^4}) - 2ln|t|] $$

This isn’t the final answer yet because our original variable is x. We should undo the substitution this time by expressing t in terms of x and attach a $+ C$ after doing so. We will revisit our expression $ \sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} = 2ax + t $. Solving for t yields 
$$t = \sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} - 2ax$$

and
$$t^4  = (\sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} - 2ax)^4$$

The integral is equal to
$$=-\frac{1}{128a^3} [\frac{1}{4}((\sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} - 2ax)^4 - \frac{1}{(\sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} - 2ax)^4}) - 2ln| \sqrt {1 + 4a^2x^2} - 2ax |] + C$$

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very indepth answer. I'll go through it: the integral from Mike's answer ends in a very long integral due to the partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

First, evaluate the simpler integral

\begin{align}
K=&\int \sqrt {1+4a^2x^2}\ dx= \int \frac{\sqrt {1+4a^2x^2}}{2x}\ d(x^2)\\
\overset{ibp}=&\ \frac12x \sqrt {1+4a^2x^2}+\frac1{4a}\sinh^{-1}(2ax)\\
\end{align}
Then, utilize $K$ below to evaluate
\begin{align}
&\int x^2\sqrt {1+4a^2x^2}\ dx\\
=&\int\frac{x}{16a^2 \sqrt{1+4a^2x^2}}\ d\left[(1+4a^2x^2)^2\right]\\
\overset{ibp}=& \ \frac x{16a^2}(1+4a^2x^2)^{3/2}-\frac1{16a^2}K \\
 =& \ \frac14 (x^3+\frac x{8a^2}) \sqrt {1+4a^2x^2}-\frac1{64a^3}\sinh^{-1}(2ax)
\end{align}